# How do I prevent scanner object from reading any more data than it has to in a loop

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

Hope this is better. I am writing a java assignment to implement a sorting technique. I used a `scanner` object within a loop to input user data to be sorted. However the `scanner` object continues to read data after array is filled and an index out of bounds error is shown. How do I deal with this.

```
public static void set1(int N)
{
    int i,c,e,f;
    double a,b;
    int[] arr1 = new int[N];
    int[] arr2 = new int[N];
    System.out.println("Please enter numbers to be sorted");

    for(i=0;i<=N;i++)
    {
        Scanner Secondin = new Scanner(System.in);
        arr1[i] =  Secondin.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `i <= N` to `i < N`. Your loop goes one too many times.

Answer (score 0):

1. From 0 to and including N is too much. a `new int[5]` has slots 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4. That's 5 slots. arr1[5] is an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because that'd be the 6th slot. Try `for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)` instead (note, `<` instead of `<=`).
2. Don't keep making scanners. Make 1 scanner, once, and keep using it.

Answer (score -3):

Inside the for loop at the end, try this code:

```
if (i == N) {
break;
}
```

This will break out of the for loop as soon as you reach the limit = N.

Comment: You are doing it wrong.
If you want your array to be of size N and if you start reading from index 0, you need to read only until N-1. As soon as your index reaches the size of N, you need to exit out of the loop. Try the below:


    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        Scanner Secondin = new Scanner(System.in);
        arr1[i] =  Secondin.nextInt();
    }